# Как карту поставить на бекграунд?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Доброго времени суток! у меня получается кнопки поместить сверху карты или сбоку или снизу, но как сделать чтоб карта была в бекграунде как [тут](http://autostarkiev.com.ua/ask.png)

вот как я делаю:

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSurrey"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onClick_Surrey"
        android:text="Surrey" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSurrey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBurnaby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick_Burnaby"
        android:text="Burnaby" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onClick_City"
        android:text="City" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

но не знаю как пустить карту в бекгроунд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout>  
    <fragment/>  
    <RelativeLayout>  
        <Button/>  
        <Button/>  
        <Button/>  
    </RelativeLayout>  
</FrameLayut>
```

Comment: благодарю)